# Issues with Matlab R2014a VS R2015a optimization boundary constraints

Tags: matlab, debugging, optimization, constraints

I have an issue. I was running a GA optimization on my work machine (R2014a) and on a friend's machine from another institution (R2015a) and have found a very serious error with the optimization files. I'm using the GA in the following way:

`[x,fval] = ga(@massstress, 7, [], [], [], [], LB, UB, @nonlinbound, intcon, options);`

The source of error between the two versions is the evaluation of the @nonlinbound condition for the code. The @nonlinbound has four relationships in my optimization, and according to the GA code, they have to be less than or equal to 0 upon evaluation of the variable set 'x' in order for the solution to be considered valid.

Evaluating the @nonlinbound for 10 solutions of 'x' on R2014a:

`ans =
   -0.0012   -0.0010    0.0000   -0.0067
   -0.0014   -0.0008    0.0000   -0.0018
   -0.0014   -0.0008    0.0000   -0.0010
   -0.0013   -0.0009    0.0000   -0.0042
   -0.0013   -0.0009    0.0000   -0.0030
   -0.0012   -0.0010    0.0000   -0.0067
   -0.0012   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0143
   -0.0014   -0.0008    0.0000   -0.0018
   -0.0014   -0.0008    0.0000   -0.0010
   -0.0013   -0.0009   -0.0000   -0.0442
   -0.0013   -0.0009    0.0000   -0.0042
   -0.0013   -0.0009   -0.0000   -0.0169
   -0.0013   -0.0009    0.0000   -0.0030
   -0.0012   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0014
   -0.0013   -0.0009   -0.0000   -0.0246`

Evaluating the @nonlinbound for 10 values of 'x' on R2015a:

`ans =
   -0.0029    0.0006    0.0001   -4.1210
   -0.0031    0.0008    0.0001   -3.4284
   -0.0032    0.0008    0.0001   -1.6713
   -0.0029    0.0006    0.0001   -8.3895
   -0.0032    0.0008    0.0001   -0.3974
   -0.0028    0.0005    0.0001   -8.4606
   -0.0032    0.0009    0.0001   -1.6834
   -0.0026    0.0004    0.0002   -6.5051
   -0.0031    0.0008    0.0001   -8.1347
   -0.0032    0.0008    0.0001   -1.4590
   -0.0030    0.0006    0.0001   -7.6538
   -0.0030    0.0006    0.0001   -2.2644
   -0.0028    0.0006    0.0001   -7.2583
   -0.0031    0.0007    0.0001   -5.7414`

As you can see, the boundary constraints aren't being met correctly, and the solutions I'm getting in R2015a are not physically feasible/manufacturable (hence the nonlinear constraints setting up realistic physical geometry..)

Any ideas, anyone? What could have changed between the two versions?

And to confirm, yes, the code is identical between the two systems. A change on one machine immediately propagated to the second machine, so I can confirm that the whole setup is cloned between the two.

Comment: I don't know much about Genetic Algorithms (if that's what you meant by GA), but aren't they meant to actually output different results every time they are evaluated, even in the same machine? Don't they use random sampling?

Comment: Yes, GA = Genetic Algorithm. They do output different results, and they do use somewhat random sampling, however because of the variance of the results I'm running the GA several times (each solution takes ~6-10 seconds to converge on this machine). So the results you're seeing that I posted are each from a GA solution (so 15 solutions on one machine, 15 solutions on the other machine). The problem is in the existence of positive values of the second set, signifying that the constraint relationships aren't being met for the converged solutions.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post `nonlinbound`?

Comment: Of course. The code itself will make sense with the following information:
1: The optimization that GA is running optimizes a circular cross section with holes.
2: The geometry is defined by small circles arranged on rings, with an unspecified and expandable amount of definitions (I'm going to be running a GA within a GA and didn't want to write multiple constraint files)
3: The strict goal of `nonlinbound.m` as shown below is to prevent interference and intersection of geometric elements.
4: The single variable passed to `nonlinbound.m` is parsed with an external .m file to get the variables

Comment: `function [c, ceq] = nonlinbound(x)
[L,ro,m,rc,rf,n,j] = math2code(x);
S1 = 0;
S2 = 0;
S3 = rf*0.10;
% BC's
c(1) = [-L/ro+10];
for i=1:m
    c([2:4]+(i-1)*3) =[[S1+rf(i)-rc(i)];
        [S2-ro+rc(i)+rf(i)];
        [S3(i)+2*rf(i)-rc(i)*sqrt(2-2*cos(2*pi/n(i)))];];
end
% BC's: Fix inter-ring overlap
i=1;q=[];
for j=1:(m-1)
    for k=(j+1):m
        q(i,1)=i;
        q(i,2)=j;
        q(i,3)=k;
        i=i+1;
    end
end
if ~isempty(q) % True if m~=1
    for i=q(:,1) % The actual constraints
        c(size(c,2)+1) = -[abs(rc(q(i,2))-rc(q(i,3)))-(rf(q(i,2))+rf(q(i,3)))];
    end
end
ceq = []
end`

Comment: 5. Polar coordinates. So for example, that very first bracketed set on the third line (`[S2-ro+rc(i)+rf(i)]`) is basically saying that subtracting `rc(i)+rf(i)`, which are both between `0` and `ro`, FROM `ro` SHOULD yield a negative value, which would satisfy the condition required by GA. You have to make sure that "correct" means a mathematically negative number for every ROW ITEM of both variables in `[c,ceq]`.

Sorry, forgot to tag. @MattG

Answer (score 0):

A solution has been found, thanks to the kind folks at Mathworks! It is quoted below:

> I did some more research on the issue and it seems that the default tolerance on the non-linear constraints was changed from MATLAB R2014a to R2015a.
>
> Since a tolerance was not specified while setting up the options for the genetic algorithm using 'gaoptimset', it used the default values : 1e-3 in R2015a and 1e-6 in R2014a.
>
> The tighter tolerance may be the reason why the constraints are violated (within tolerance) in R2015a.
>
> To set the tolerances, you can use the following syntax:
>
> > `options.TolCon = 1e-6;`

I can confirm that this did indeed correct my issue. Thank you very much, Raghav P. of Mathworks!

Note: The options must first be collected before being set using the following code:

`options = gaoptimset(@ga);`